# Backbone/jQuery event for when the client tries to go forward/go back?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm building a backbone app and am learning about how to use Backbone's pushState. My app's main view is a 'Feed' view, which displays a bunch of items. When you click on an item, it loads a new item 'Show' view, and slips it into the page.

Right now, I've successfully got my app using pushState true to enter in the browser's history  a record for each article viewed.

However, when I go 'back' in my browser's history, I'd like to trigger an event to do some stuff on the show view. Is there a backbone or jQuery event/function that I can use to detect when the user has selected to go forward/back in history?

It would be great to use an backbone event like:

```
 events: {
  'dblclick':'test'
 },
```

Comment: There are [routing events](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route) but I don't think there is anything specific to the *back* button.

Comment: hmm interesting, i'm thinking about whether I can use these for my goal here. FYI I don't just mean a back button click, i mean the general act of navigating back/forward in the browser history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a view for an App controller you can use this trick of passing the window object as your `el` option to the View.  With the window object held in the View you'll get all the window events bound to your events hash such that you could add an event like `popstate` to your hash and you'll get a back button event.

I quickly tested this so it should work for you:

```
var App = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
      "popstate":          "onPopState"
    },
    onPopState : function onPopState() {
        console.log("onPopState");
    }
});
var MainApp = new App({ el : window });
```

Comment: hey Bryan, sorry it took so long for me to loop back through to this. I tried it out and you're right! this will result in a console log whenever the client tries to go forward/back. Any way to differentiate between the two though? (eg know if the client is trying to go back vs forward?)

Comment: Yeah, if you're pushing state into the pushState command you'll get that back in an event.  Change `onPopState()` to be `onPopState(event)` and see this for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate#The_popstate_event

Comment: thanks! any thoughts on cross-browser support for this sort of setup?